# Open Flash Chart - How to add multiple points for a single value x?

Tags: flash, charts

Is there a way to plot multiple data for the same value x? For example following points:

[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 6], [2, 9], [3, 11], [4, 11]...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is: ScatterChart